# pairwise_t_test() doesn't return statistic and estimate

Tags: r, t-test, rstatix

I am a beginner in R and do not understand why `pairwise_t_test()` from the `rstatix` package does not show the t-value and cohen's d.

```r
pairwise_t_test(data = filtered_normdata, BZO_RWgesamt ~ Alter, p.adjust.method = "none")
# A tibble: 36 × 9
   .y.       group1 group2    n1    n2        p p.signif    p.adj p.adj.signif
 * <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       
 1 BZO_RWge… 11     12        95    90 4.26e- 2 *        4.26e- 2 *           
 2 BZO_RWge… 11     13        95    90 6.17e- 5 ****     6.17e- 5 ****        
 3 BZO_RWge… 12     13        90    90 4.85e- 2 *        4.85e- 2 *           
 4 BZO_RWge… 11     14        95    74 4.85e- 9 ****     4.85e- 9 ****        
 5 BZO_RWge… 12     14        90    74 8.21e- 5 ****     8.21e- 5 ****        
 6 BZO_RWge… 13     14        90    74 3.72e- 2 *        3.72e- 2 *           
 7 BZO_RWge… 11     15        95    68 8.39e-18 ****     8.39e-18 ****        
 8 BZO_RWge… 12     15        90    68 1.22e-11 ****     1.22e-11 ****        
 9 BZO_RWge… 13     15        90    68 5   e- 7 ****     5   e- 7 ****        
10 BZO_RWge… 14     15        74    68 3.73e- 3 **       3.73e- 3 **          
# ℹ 26 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I already tried to get the statistic and estimate like this:

```r
BZO_H2_w <- pairwise_t_test(data = filtered_normdata, BZO_RWgesamt ~ Alter, p.adjust.method = "none")
```

`BZO_H2_w$estimate` and `BZO_H2_w$statistic`

but it didn't work. I would be really thankful if someone can help me :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant pairwise_t_test() instead of xx

Comment: What does `filtered_normdata` look like? If it's a lot, take a subsample and share that. E.g: `dput(head(filtered_normdata))`

Comment: Thank you for your question! It's a lot but I took this subsample: 
 head(select(filtered_normdata, Alter, BZO_RWgesamt))
`# A tibble: 6 × 2
Alter BZO_RWgesamt
<fct>        <dbl>
1 11             138
2 11             122
3 11             126
4 11             132
5 11             130
6 11             140
>`

Comment: Could you do a `dput()` of that subsample and add it to your question?

Comment: Yes, do you mean like this?

`structure(list(Alter = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"), class = "factor"), 
    BZO_RWgesamt = structure(c(138, 122, 126, 132, 130, 140), label = "Bearbeitete Zielobjekte Endergebnis", format.spss = "F8.0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: Yes, although it only appears to include values for one of the groups.

Comment: Only for one of the groups of "Alter"? Is that why pairwise_t_test() is not correct working? I don't understand what I did wrong...

Comment: In that subset only one group of Alter is present, but in the parent data.frame there are 11, named "9", "10", … "19". Try `subs <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(filtered_normdata, filtered_normdata$Alter), head, 5)[1:3])
`, it should give a subsample of the three first groups, with five samples in each. Then `dput(subs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the function from `rstatix` that you are asking about then it only seems to return the full detail of the tests if you request not to use a pooled standard deviation for the t-tests (`pool.sd=FALSE`).

If you look at the code, `pairwise_t_test` calls the R function `stats::pairwise.t.test` when you use a pooled SD, but uses a repeated application of `stats::t.test` when `pool.sd=FALSE`.  It then uses `broom::tidy` to collate the statistics into a table.

So I don't think there's a good statistical reason for the difference in reporting, it just relies on different base functions, and while the R function `t.test` does return the t-statistic etc, `pairwise.t.test` only returns a matrix of p-values.

You *can* get the detail of the pairwise t-tests with pooled SD if you use `lm` to get a linear model (ANOVA) then `emmeans` to get the pairwise contrasts.  Note the p-values from `emmeans` are the same as from `pairwise.t.test` with the pooled SD, but it returns the estimate and statistic as well.

So, with some toy data:

```
> dat <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,10), y=rnorm(100))
> 
> rstatix::pairwise_t_test(dat, y~x, detailed=TRUE)

# A tibble: 45 × 10
   .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2     p method p.adj p.signif p.adj.signif
 * <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>       
 1 y     1      2         10    10 0.536 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 2 y     1      3         10    10 0.453 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 3 y     2      3         10    10 0.896 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 4 y     1      4         10    10 0.427 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 5 y     2      4         10    10 0.86  T-test     1 ns       ns          
 6 y     3      4         10    10 0.964 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 7 y     1      5         10    10 0.781 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 8 y     2      5         10    10 0.733 T-test     1 ns       ns          
 9 y     3      5         10    10 0.636 T-test     1 ns       ns          
10 y     4      5         10    10 0.605 T-test     1 ns       ns          
# ℹ 35 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

> rstatix::pairwise_t_test(dat, y~x, pool.sd=FALSE, detailed = TRUE)

# A tibble: 45 × 17
   estimate estimate1 estimate2 .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p    df conf.low conf.high method alternative p.adj p.adj.signif
 *    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       
 1  -0.276    -0.318   -0.0417  y     1      2         10    10   -0.725  0.479  15.6   -1.08      0.533 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 2  -0.334    -0.318    0.0166  y     1      3         10    10   -0.760  0.457  18.0   -1.26      0.590 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 3  -0.354    -0.318    0.0367  y     1      4         10    10   -0.782  0.445  18.0   -1.31      0.598 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 4  -0.124    -0.318   -0.194   y     1      5         10    10   -0.306  0.763  17.0   -0.977     0.729 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 5  -0.209    -0.318   -0.109   y     1      6         10    10   -0.458  0.653  18.0   -1.17      0.749 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 6  -0.0428   -0.318   -0.275   y     1      7         10    10   -0.104  0.918  17.3   -0.909     0.823 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 7   0.0437   -0.318   -0.361   y     1      8         10    10    0.0933 0.927  17.9   -0.940     1.03  T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 8  -0.150    -0.318   -0.167   y     1      9         10    10   -0.320  0.752  17.9   -1.14      0.835 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
 9  -0.321    -0.318    0.00292 y     1      10        10    10   -0.616  0.546  16.9   -1.42      0.778 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
10  -0.0583   -0.0417   0.0166  y     2      3         10    10   -0.158  0.876  16.0   -0.840     0.724 T-test two.sided       1 ns          
# ℹ 35 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

> mod1 <- lm(data=dat , y~factor(x)) 
> emmeans::emmeans(mod1, pairwise ~ x, adjust="none", infer=c(TRUE, TRUE))$contrast

 contrast estimate    SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 x1 - x2   -0.2759 0.444 90   -1.158    0.606  -0.622  0.5357
 x1 - x3   -0.3343 0.444 90   -1.216    0.547  -0.753  0.4533
 x1 - x4   -0.3543 0.444 90   -1.236    0.527  -0.798  0.4268
 x1 - x5   -0.1238 0.444 90   -1.006    0.758  -0.279  0.7809
 x1 - x6   -0.2086 0.444 90   -1.090    0.673  -0.470  0.6395
 x1 - x7   -0.0428 0.444 90   -0.925    0.839  -0.096  0.9234
 x1 - x8    0.0437 0.444 90   -0.838    0.925   0.098  0.9218
 x1 - x9   -0.1503 0.444 90   -1.032    0.731  -0.339  0.7357
 x1 - x10  -0.3206 0.444 90   -1.202    0.561  -0.722  0.4720
 x2 - x3   -0.0583 0.444 90   -0.940    0.823  -0.131  0.8957
 x2 - x4   -0.0784 0.444 90   -0.960    0.803  -0.177  0.8602
 x2 - x5    0.1521 0.444 90   -0.730    1.034   0.343  0.7326
 x2 - x6    0.0673 0.444 90   -0.814    0.949   0.152  0.8798
 x2 - x7    0.2331 0.444 90   -0.649    1.115   0.525  0.6007
 x2 - x8    0.3196 0.444 90   -0.562    1.201   0.720  0.4733
 x2 - x9    0.1257 0.444 90   -0.756    1.007   0.283  0.7777
 x2 - x10  -0.0446 0.444 90   -0.926    0.837  -0.101  0.9201
 x3 - x4   -0.0201 0.444 90   -0.902    0.862  -0.045  0.9640
 x3 - x5    0.2105 0.444 90   -0.671    1.092   0.474  0.6365
 x3 - x6    0.1257 0.444 90   -0.756    1.007   0.283  0.7777
 x3 - x7    0.2915 0.444 90   -0.590    1.173   0.657  0.5130
 x3 - x8    0.3779 0.444 90   -0.504    1.260   0.852  0.3967
 x3 - x9    0.1840 0.444 90   -0.698    1.066   0.415  0.6794
 x3 - x10   0.0137 0.444 90   -0.868    0.895   0.031  0.9754
 x4 - x5    0.2305 0.444 90   -0.651    1.112   0.519  0.6047
 x4 - x6    0.1457 0.444 90   -0.736    1.027   0.328  0.7434
 x4 - x7    0.3116 0.444 90   -0.570    1.193   0.702  0.4845
 x4 - x8    0.3980 0.444 90   -0.484    1.280   0.897  0.3722
 x4 - x9    0.2041 0.444 90   -0.678    1.086   0.460  0.6468
 x4 - x10   0.0338 0.444 90   -0.848    0.915   0.076  0.9395
 x5 - x6   -0.0848 0.444 90   -0.967    0.797  -0.191  0.8489
 x5 - x7    0.0810 0.444 90   -0.801    0.963   0.183  0.8556
 x5 - x8    0.1675 0.444 90   -0.714    1.049   0.377  0.7068
 x5 - x9   -0.0265 0.444 90   -0.908    0.855  -0.060  0.9526
 x5 - x10  -0.1968 0.444 90   -1.078    0.685  -0.443  0.6586
 x6 - x7    0.1658 0.444 90   -0.716    1.048   0.374  0.7096
 x6 - x8    0.2523 0.444 90   -0.629    1.134   0.568  0.5712
 x6 - x9    0.0583 0.444 90   -0.823    0.940   0.131  0.8957
 x6 - x10  -0.1120 0.444 90   -0.994    0.770  -0.252  0.8014
 x7 - x8    0.0865 0.444 90   -0.795    0.968   0.195  0.8460
 x7 - x9   -0.1075 0.444 90   -0.989    0.774  -0.242  0.8092
 x7 - x10  -0.2778 0.444 90   -1.160    0.604  -0.626  0.5330
 x8 - x9   -0.1939 0.444 90   -1.076    0.688  -0.437  0.6632
 x8 - x10  -0.3642 0.444 90   -1.246    0.517  -0.821  0.4140
 x9 - x10  -0.1703 0.444 90   -1.052    0.711  -0.384  0.7021
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It worked with emmeans! Is there a rule when to use the pooled.sd and when not to do it?

Comment: Using a pooled standard deviation is more efficient but it assumes the true underlying standard deviations are equal across groups.  In your case you seem to have 50 to 100 observations per group, so I would think it's safer to use individual standard deviation for each test `(pool.sd=FALSE)`, and these will be well estimated.  Also if you're happy with my answer you can 'accept' it.